# How to start the GUI in Centos 8?

Tags: centos, gui, systemctl

I had a fresh instantiation on Centos 8. I installed Server and GUI. everything was working fine. But then, I needed to install the Nvidia drivers for my GPUs. To install the Nvidia drivers, I followed these [instructions](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/install-nvidia-drivers-on-centos-8-linux-instructions/td-p/9823426).

But now, I can't get the graphical interface to show up. When the PC boots up, I get a black screen unit I press Alt + F5 which prompts me to log in using the multi-user mode instead of graphical.

I tried to execute `sudo inti 5` which did not do anything. This command usually switch to graphical interface.

I also tried `systemctl isolate graphical.target`

When I execute `systemctl get-default` I get `graphical.target` as expected. But when I reboot, the GUI never comes up. the only way I can get into the PC is by pressing ALT + F5 and login using the command line.

I don't know if this is related to my problem or now. But, the command  `echo $DISPLAY` returns blank line as it's not set.

How can I bring the GUI back up?

**UPDATED**
Here are the output of the commands suggested below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the NVIDIA driver you installed using this command:

```
sh ./NVIDIA-Linux*.run --uninstall
```

Now install the NVIDIA drivers from the [ELrepo web site](https://elrepo.org).  First install the ELrepo repository (as described on the website) then install “kmod-nvidia” through

```
dnf install kmod-nvidia
```

That way you have an install that is reliable.  Those instructions you found might work but fail if you don’t have the right conditions.  The ELrepo packages contain the same drivers from the nvidia web site, just in a more reliable method of installing and updating them.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did exactly what you asked. the installer installed lots of packages. but how can I get the GUI back up? I tried rebooting, still I can't do anything unless I press Alt + F5 and login using the command line. Also, is there a way to validate that the nvidia drivers are installed correctly?

Comment: I’d suggest you check that the nvidia driver is loaded (`lsmod | grep nvidia`) and then look for errors in the GDM service (`systemctl status gdm.service`)

Comment: I am not sure I know what I am looking for. I just updated my question with a screenshot of the output. Also the command `tail /var/log/Xorg.9.log` shows `71.206 (II) UnloadModule: "libinput" and the `tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log`  shows `Fatal server error: [11.652] (EE) no screen found(EE)`

Comment: There is an earlier error that should have EE in the X log